# JavaScript: Creating totally new HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html

**Question:**

I wanted to know if it was possible to create totally new HTML pages with JavaScript.

Example:
I am a user, I put something in a form and it creates a page with what the user wrote.
(Sort of like PasteBin)

---

**Research:**

I have tried searching this question up, but I didn't find what I was quite looking for. Some open up frames, and some just make the main index page. However, I want users to make the page and have it visible for others.

---

**Anything Else:**

I know this can be done in PHP. However, I don't know much about the language. I wanted to know if this was possible in JavaScript because I know a good bit about it.

Any help is appreciated. If this is possible, could you please leave some code or a link to any tutorial showing how to do this?

---

Thank you. -Hutch

---

**EDIT:**

I will be taking a look at Node.js (Thanks, Tyler!)

Thank you all for the posts!

Comment: Sure, just create new DOM elements and add them dynamically.

Comment: The problem is that you'd need to store the data somewhere. JavaScript doesn't save data. You'd need to use local storage, a server-side solution, or an absurdly long URL query string.

Comment: _“I want users to make the page and have it visible for others”_ – well, that requires storing them somewhere server side, so that they can be read again from there and delivered to other users.

Comment: @CBroe true, but you could still use JS via Node.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately what you're trying to do requires that the data be stored somewhere. Necessitating some kind of server side storage.

And when you use server-side storage you need some intermediary server-side language like PHP, or Node.js.

Lucky for you Node.js is written entirely in Javascript and executed on the server, so it should be very familiar for you if you're good with Javascript.

Comment: By "Node" do you mean "Node.js" (this here: http://nodejs.org/)?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean. I'll update my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll look into Node.js :)

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept one of the answers if they qualify as a solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I like using PHP and JavaScript with jQuery.

createPage.php

```
if (isset($_POST['str'])) {
    $name = 'page_'.time().'.html';
    file_put_contents('/var/www/html/pages/'.$name, $_POST['str']);
}
```

paste.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#done').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'createPage.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                str: $('#content').val()
            }
        })
        .done(function(msg) {
            $('#result').text(msg);
        });
    });
});
</script>

<textarea id="content" rows="30" cols="120"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="done" value="Create" /><br />
<div id="result"></result>
```